# Flutter and Azure SSO

Tags: flutter, azure, single-sign-on, saml

I am developing a flutter application for my company. In my company, many web applications use Azure SSO and SAML connections, and there is no need to log in repeatedly when switching between sites. I want to direct redirection to these sites with the in-application web browser in the mobile application I have developed. What are the steps and details I should follow in Azure or Flutter for this? Is such a system possible?

```
static final Config config = new Config(
    tenant: "YOUR_TENANT_ID",
    clientId: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
    scope: "openid profile offline_access",
    redirectUri: "your redirect url available in azure portal",
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    webUseRedirect: true,
    loader: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://your_base_url/logout', //optional
  );

  final AadOAuth oauth = new AadOAuth(config);

final result = await oauth.login();
```

This code uses the aad_oauth library. I log in and receive an access token, but I cannot access sites affiliated with the institution that have the same login method. Sometimes it returns a 401 UNAUTHORIZED error and sometimes it redirects back to the login page.

Comment: can you please share any code that you have tried.

Comment: I added code for login process